# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSchema()

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

My `solr` version is `solr-4.4.0`. I get the following error when starting `sold` after I add `DataImporter` into `solrconfig.xml`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSchema()Lorg/apache/solr/schema/IndexSchema;
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.<init>(DataImporter.java:101)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:102)
    ... 15 more
```

I have this list of Jar files in my lib folder:
lib
ext

- jetty-jmx-8.1.10.v20130312.jar jetty-webapp-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- jetty-continuation-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- jetty-security-8.1.10.v20130312.jar jetty-xml-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- jetty-deploy-8.1.10.v20130312.jar jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar servlet-api-3.0.jar
- jetty-io-8.1.10.v20130312.jar jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
- solr-dataimporthandler-4.1.0.jar

I have `solr.war` in `webapps` folder (not sure if this is relevant, but seems someone mentioned `solr.war` in another thread).

```
ls -l webapps/solr.war 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 myusername  mygroup  25099205 Jul 19 02:58 webapps/solr.war
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to recompile the war file and replace the solr.war file in your webapps directory with the new war file in the dist directory.

Answer (score -1):

I solve my problem replacing the 2 jar's from dataimport. The error occurs because i am using a different core and dataimport lib version (core 4.6 and dataimport 4.3.1)